# NGINX Ingress Annotations creates 404

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have an NGINX Ingress sitting in front of a few nodejs services. I want to restrict the path /graphql to only POST and only content-type=application/json

I've added the following annotation, which seems to work in terms of the restriction, but valid requests now return a 404

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /graphql {
      limit_except OPTIONS POST {
         deny all;
      }

      if ($http_content_type != "application/json") {
          return 403;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Could you add some details to the question? What request are OK, what requests return a 404? As I understand your restriction of /graphql and POST content-type is working?  It is better to add request examples.

Comment: so both conditionals work. 
If I make a GET request it returns 403
If I make a request without content-type="application/json" header set it returns 403

But if I make a correct request: POST request with the header set to /graphql I just get a 404

Comment: Don't duplicate questions, edit the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `location` {} block doesn't have an upstream like the regular paths defined in the nginx ingress.
Get the nginx ingress configuration from `ingress-nginx-controller` pod:

```
$ kubectl exec -n your-ingress-nginx-namespace ingress-nginx-controller-xxx-xxx -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And check some other location {} block to find what you might need for your `/graphql` location {} configuration.

The following basic `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` works for me (requests other than POST and content-type=application/json return 403 status code, valid requests are OK):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cms-ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /graphql {
          limit_except OPTIONS POST {
             deny all;
          }
          if ($http_content_type != "application/json") {
              return 403;
          }
          set $proxy_upstream_name "default-nginx-80";
          proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;
      }
spec:
...
```

Also, be aware of [If is Evil... when used in location context](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).
So, I advise you to test your final configuration thoroughly before putting it in production.

Comment: is there a better way than the if statement to achieve the same result?

Comment: @Ben Gannaway, I think you can't do the http_content_type check in ingress any better way.